# UK student visa refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, study

I was recently refused twice for a Tier 4 student visa. In the first application, my step-father had provided all the required documents for proof of money. However, our connection was doubted and, therefore, I had no proof of funds.

[image]

In the second, my mother had provided savings accounts as proof of funds; the university had looked through it all and provided me with a second CAS. Again, this was refused, on the grounds that apparently 6-8 of the accounts have already been used for another UK tier 4 visa. This makes no sense considering that this was my mother and the money was in savings account for my benefit.

[image]

I understand there can be an administrative review, but what are my chances of succeeding? If I were to apply again for next academic year, will my chances be hurt by these refusals?

Comment: I am not sure if this is for us or for Expats http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions Would you please scan and redact your refusal notices and 'edit' your question using this link... http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/79404/edit

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until you upload a scan or transcript of the refusal notice(s) with your personal info blacked out, see [Why do you want to see UK refusal notices?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3788/32134)

Comment: @mts I totally agree with your comment, but I think there's a rep hurdle to get in to META, no?

Comment: @GayotFow the link is only posted as a reference so it should not matter. To be fair I have given the OP a +1 for free right now so that they clear the 5 rep hurdle for participating in META.

Comment: @mts Ah! I just did it too

Comment: Did you use any company or agent to help compile the paperwork and forms?

Comment: @mkennedy nice one!

Comment: @mkennedy no i did not, should've I? and added printscreens

Comment: @A.Ren this is a refusal under Paragraph 245 which pretty much means we must refer you to Expats http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions  You should recognize that somebody who tries to meet the requirements using 8 bank accounts is headed for trouble. Also, I haven't looked to see if the Saigon Commercial Bank is on their list of untrustworthy banks, and you should definitely raise the issue when you post to Expats.  The rest of your refusal looks fairly straight-forward, I can't see it being a show-stopper for very long.

Comment: I have retracted my "unclear"-close vote, this should be closed as off-topic and referred to Expats.

Comment: You need to get a solicitor, and should have done so before the first application.  Never apply on your own.

Comment: I asked about an agent because I wondered how the bank accounts could have been used already. An unscrupulous agent could have created fake accounts.